# 17.10 After upgrade, System BootOrder not found

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi, 17.10

Today I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the upgrade, my HP EliteBook 840 G1 was stuck in a bootloop, with an error message appearing for the blink of an eye:

> System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
>
> Creating boot entry "Boot000B" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.erf"
>
> Reset System

Luckily, I'm still able to boot into Ubuntu by using the manual boot device option of my UEFI BIOS, where I can select "ubuntu" and boot it. However, if I'm advising my BIOS to use "OS Boot Manager", the error message appears again.

Is there a way to fix this and make my Notebook boot normally again, instead of having to boot up Ubuntu manually?

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? Im having the same issue

Comment: Not exactly solved. After trying the Ubuntu version 17.10 und 16.04 LTS from the website and still suffering from the very same problem, I used an old version of 17.10 from December (which I had still on my disk) and the issue was resolved. However, installing updates will only bring it up again. The only updates I can install without the error occurring again are security updates via sudo unattended-upgrades -d .

Comment: I've managed to boot into Ubuntu/Windows, by booting Ubuntu from LiveCD and then manually setting boot order through efibootmanager. Now I have issue that boot order is not preserved.

Comment: I have seen older UEFI firmware that always looks for Windows boot loader before any others regardless of Boot Order.  Find a Windows method to change the Boot Order and see if it stays after power cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For people still finding this question: It was answered in a later thread: [system bootOrder not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found/1103331)