# HP EliteBook 8570p Ubuntu grub is not launched

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have recently installed a dual boot on my EliteBook, and it works, except for the fact that the grub isn't automatically loading.

When I turn on my computer, it goes back and forth indefinitely between the HP launching screep (with a gray logo in the center) to a black screen with an error message in the upper left corner (too fast to read).

I can manually escape this loop by pressing F9 then "Boot from EFI" --> ".[something here]" --> "ubuntu" --> grubx64.efi", the grub then loads and I can choose between the Windows (10) or Ubuntu (18.04) launchers, so the grub itself is functionnal, but it doesn't pop up without manual intervention.

I've found a few posts about efibootmgr and I read the manual, so I tried to use it.
It says :

`BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
Boot0000* Notebook Upgrade Bay
Boot0001* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot0002* Notebook Ethernet
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0004* ubuntu
...
Boot0013* ubuntu
Boot0014* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0015* ubuntu
...
Boot005F* ubuntu`
(This definitely looks weird...)

`$ sudo efibootmgr -n 0003` successfully sets `NextBoot` to `0003`, but it only works once.

`$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0000,0001,0002` works too, and the options display

`BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0001,0002
...`
But it seems to be overwritten upon restart, and the next launch goes into the infinite loop again, and options display the default `BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002` again.

Thanks for your help, I can manage manually in the meantime but I would appreciate to not have to do this indefinitely...

P.S.: Is it really safe to remove the duplicates of `BootXXXX* ubuntu` using `$ sudo -B -b 005F` ? Is there a way to do it more than one at a time, like `$ sudo -B -b 0030-005F` or something else ?

...

I have now identified both the error message and the source of all these boots :

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.

Creating boot entry "Boot007B" with label "ubuntu" for file "EFI\ubuntu\shimx.efi"


Reset system
```

I may have quite a bit of manual deleting on my hands...

...

I am back to a reasonable amount of boots (4), and I've tried to apply what was explained on the `System BootOrder not found` post, but I'm having trouble adapting to my own boot options panel... I do have a "Security" panel, but there's no "load trusted EFI file" option in there... I tried a few things with the "Custom Boot" and "Secure Boot" options, but none of that was successful.

...

Nope, nothing works, I tried boot-repair too, but it doesn't change a thing. I even went through reinstalling GRUB, but it did not solve my problem, and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing with boot entries since I first explored the Linux world and started experimenting with many distros and dual booting as well, and I assure you there's nothing wrong to delete useless entries, unless you don't know what each of them is called for. But your list is huge, I must say. I believe you've been messing with Ubuntu installation very much, haven't you?

So yeah, before doing anything, read all the entries with

```
efibootmgr -v
```

All that linked to wrong efi file path, you are safe to remove. Also, consider deleting those files from your ESP (warning: bold experts only!).

Also, record a video with that error that shows up on boot screen to make it clear.

Comment: Actually, I suspect the list is appended each time I manually boot, so 5F is presumably just the number of times I've powered on my computer... Also, I used -v, and they are all identical. It says `HD(2,GPT,af7221d5-10fd-48ad-b867-f4b2b6670180,0xe1800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)`

Comment: Wow. How about deleting all the ubuntu entries and manually create one?

Comment: Can I do that more efficiently than one at a time ? 5F is a lot...

Comment: I'm afraid not. The man page should tell you more, though. But it's always better to do dangerous actions one by one.

Comment: Hey, hope this helps too https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. Also, allow me to correct my previous comment : 91 is a lot.

Comment: Hell, sorry to know that. Obviously, duplicates are never visually okay, so taking care of boot entries would be great before proceeding to bios stuff