# "System bootOrder not found. Initializing default. Reset system."

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Today all of the sudden my laptop EliteBook 840 G3 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10 didn't start up anymore. Instead it is stuck in a infinite loop. Right after the HP logo shows up I get the error message:

"System BootOrder not found. Initializing default. Reset System."

It seems like I am not the only person around having this issue. But i tried several solutions and none of them worked for me so far:

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found) doesn't work for me because I can't unlock few more options. Turning on "secure boot" doesn't unlock any more.

[This solution](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi) didn't cause any error messages on the way but also didn't solve my problem.

My third try was to follow [this wiki article](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/). But I had some error messages on the way. Maybe you could have a [look at my console](https://pastebin.com/Jr5Pdv6v)? It fails because it cannot open /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. Even when I switch into the directory it can't list the ubuntu directory. This seems weird to me.

Does anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong or what else is going wrong there and how I could fix this problem?

Comment: The /EFI/ubuntu is now normally mounted with 0077 in fstab which gives no access, probably for security. Before it used defaults & you could easily see & modify settings. I change my & Boot-Repair also does, so it can do updates. I may change back in future for security. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a really solution for this problem. So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu and even this failed with the error that grub couldn't be installed.

So all I could do was to format my disk and start all over again. But since a lot of people seem to have problems with dualboot I decided this time to reinstall only ubuntu and leave windows out. In case I want to have windows too I will install it on it's own disk.