# efibootmgr problem, dual-boot, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, 19.10, efibootmgr

I recently purchased a laptop that had no OS's installed. Fine. I installed a fresh Windows 8.1 (the original OS), and Ubuntu 19.10. No problem.

However, when it boots, it flashes a very quick message something like:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
```

`sudo efibootmgr`

```
BootCurrent: 0015
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive
Boot0002* UEFI:USB Device
Boot0003* UEFI:Network Device
Boot000D* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0012* UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0013* UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0015* UEFI: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075
```

Now if I force `sudo efibootmgr --bootnext 0000` and then reboot, the error message no longer shows, but that only lasts for one boot.

I can't seem to change `BootCurrent` to 0000.

How can I change `BootCurrent` to follow the specified `BootOrder`?

Comment: Any helpful thing https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found

Comment: @nobody thanks so much for the lead! I'll check it out and report back later.

Comment: @nobody please see my answer. Although your link didn't provide the final solution, it gave me the courage to try something I wasn't brave enough to try yesterday. Thanks again for the assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I *think* I have it fixed. It still appears to be booting fine into Ubuntu and Windows, but without the error message.

@nobody posted a nice link that exactly described my problem. However, the fixes didn't apply to me, because my BIOS doesn't have the options outlined in the answers.

I ended up doing a `sudo efibootmgr -c` which created a new entry "Boot0004* Linux", and it changed the "BootCurrent" and "BootOrder" values to this:

`sudo efibootmgr`

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0015,0013,0012,000D
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0004* Linux
Boot000D* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0012* UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0013* UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Boot0015* UEFI: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075
```

The new "BootCurrent" and "BootOrder" values don't make a lot of sense to me... but it appears to work...

Comment: UEFI has a boot once and default BootOrder. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr You use efibootmgr and it -o parameter, see also `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your input. There's actually three parameters... BootCurrent, BootNext, and BootOrder. Can't do much about BootCurrent, but the last two can be set with efibootmgr. I ended up creating a NEW entry, and that changed BootCurrent and BootOrder, as you can see by comparing my two before and after examples.