# System bootOrder not found. Inizializing defaults

Tags: boot, uefi, windows

I don't know what to say. I have Ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10. I did anything

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044518/1103062).

Comment: I find secure boot control and key management