# Ubuntu System BootOrder not found on Acer Aspire F5-573

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios, acer

I have had Ubuntu system on my machine for a year now, all working perfectly. Today when I wanted to access Ubuntu I got the following message:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults. Creating boot entry "Boot000A" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" Reset System
```

And obviously the system resets.

There is apparently working solution for that ([system bootOrder not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found)), however I have followed all described steps and it didn't work.
I describe my steps below and also add some photos - could you please verify if I'm doing it ok?

1. Enter 'Select an UEFI file as trusted for' executing in the 'Security tab'
2. It shows HDD1, so entering it, then <ubuntu
   **Here is on of my questions:** Isn't that weird that I have only HDD1 option (and do not have HDD0 option as well as described in the solution? In my boot priority order I have HDD0 shown too.
3. In the  directory, it shows items as on the photo #2. I chose shimx64.efi, added description 'UBUNTU', hit 'YES'. The message popped up 'The FILE is exist'.
4. Retured to the main directory and selected 'Boot' tab
5. The boot tab looked like on the photo #3. I moved EFI File Boot 2: ubuntushimxefi on the second position after Windows Boot Manager.
   **My another question:** I don't have any item named UBUNTU like described in the solution.
6. Saved and exit. The problem occured again.

[Photo #1 - security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li0SG.jpg)

[Photo #2 - after accessing HDD1 and ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxYI9.png)

[Photo #3 - boot tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnhgI.jpg)

Comment: Any one knows the solution? Any suggestions? I really need to access Ubuntu as I have got very important projects there...

Answer (score 0):

You did right thing but you struck in renaming process. Please choose a different name... Instead of `ubuntu` use `ubun` or as per your wish, because you already used `ubuntu`. That's why it is not accepting it.